# How can I put back dll into xap file after extract?

Tags: silverlight, zip, xap

I extract an xap file using winzip and edit some resources.

Is there any way I can pack the dlls back into the xap file?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).  Just use 'Open Archive' on the xap and then drag and drop files into it.